# What are the Addams family?

Tags: addams-family

Honestly, there are **too many questions** I have about *The Addams Family*, as people and a series/franchise that may be hard to answer. Granted, with decades of history and various interpretations and versions, it could be a lot to guess at... and especially because its' a comedy series, it may simply may not be made to make "logical" sense... so I'll stick mostly to the 1990s movies, the comedic H-B cartoon of the same time, and maybe make reference to the upcoming 2010s CGI film.

So, that being said... are the Addams even *human?* Or, perhaps "traditionally mortal" would be the best description?

Considering various members of the family have been shot, stabbed, electrocuted, flung through the air, crushed, run over, burned, and blown up with NO evident damage... can they be considered "mortal"? I mean, they *do* have a graveyard with past family members... but it's been *implied* at least that these family members are capable of waking up at odd times. So outside of the comedic applications... are they able to "die" as normal humans?

Subsequently... if they *are* traditionally human, then do Gomez, Pugsley, Fester and Wednesday have some kind of healing factor? The amount of dangerous stuff they have participated in with each other for "fun" would *kill* a normal person, but they seem to bounce back from them, and even *enjoy* it.  That **has** to be more than mere masochism. I suppose magic and cartoon-like comedy would explain it, but again, it's never made that plain a statement.

Are there any canon sources which might explain all of this?

Comment: Related to #8: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45663/who-built-lurch-the-addams-familys-butler

Comment: *"_Come,every member of our clan - **living, dead** - and undecided and let us celebrate what is to be an Addams._"* - Addams Family Musical. Note that Morticia, Gomez and the kids all appear in the "alive" category.

Comment: What are the Adams family, you say? Well ... \*Breaks into song\* ... "Their creepy and their kooky. Mysterious and spooky. Their all together ooky. The Adams family!"

Comment: @Caleblolololol....... funny.

Comment: Given that The Adams Family originally was a cartoon (comic panels, specifically), I would argue that their survivability is due to the rule of cartoon physics, well established in the movie Who Framed Roger Rabbit.

Comment: Related to [_"Addams family: any indication that Gomez, his wife and kids are supernatural?"_](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/270042/addams-family-any-indication-that-gomez-his-wife-and-kids-are-supernatural)